# CSS Navigation Bar Hover - Background Change

Tags: css, navigation, hover

When I was creating a navigation bar, I wanted to make its fields change colour when hovered. However, the colour doesn't seem to fill the whole height of the navigation bar. Here is my code:

```css
#nav {
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#nav ul li {
float:left;
margin: 20px;
}

#nav ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
line-height:40px; 
color: gray;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 25px;
display: block;
}

#nav ul li a:hover { 
color: black;
background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

How can I make the colour fill the whole height of the navigation bar when hovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list container`#nav ul li` has `margin:margin: 20px;` which will not take any color change...I would go with padding instead...

see snippet

```css
#nav {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
#nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
  color: green;
  background-color: gray;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```